# How to send large text to server flutter

Tags: flutter

If i have a large String and want to send it to server , should save it as a local File and then send the file using http multipart Request ?
or can send that String as a txt file without saving it locally ?

Comment: Depends on the server API, what it expects. Both multipart and string works from the application point of view.

Comment: @user18309290 so if i have write novel app and i want to upload big chapter should save it locally and then upload the file ?? because in this case i dont think its a proper way to do it  , what do you think ?

Comment: If it is not saved in a file in the first place, then just send it as it is assuming the server API supports that.

Comment: I don't think this queston is specific to flutter development